# How many GPUs are out there?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I could not find numbers on how many modern GPUs are sold up to date by both Nvidia and AMD? By modern, I mean general purpose programmable by CUDA, OpenCL or some other technology. Do anybody knows?

Thanks.

Comment: I am writing my thesis and want to write about tremendous growth in GPU computing and its impact on mainstream computing. The numbers would indeed help in making my point.

Comment: Try  John Peddie Reasearch reports http://jonpeddie.com/publications/pc_gaming_hardware_market_report/

Answer (score 3):

There are some numbers: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/GPU-videocard-Nvidia-AMD,6533.html "total GPU shipments in Q3 2008 of more than 111 million units.", half of them are cuda- and opecl- disabled intel

So, total number of CUDA/OpenCL enabled GPUs is around 50 mln * 4 (4 Q in a year) * 4 (up to 4 years of modern GPU produced) ~= 0.8 - 1.2 billions. This is only an estimate, and real numbers can vary from 0.05 to 2 billion.

`some other technology` can mean GP programming with shaders, so number is so high. CUDA is here for 5 years, OpenCL is very young, Stream is not so popular (?). Not all modern cards allow using of CUDA or OpenCL...

Comment: user600029, I have exact number from NVIDIA about CUDA-enabled devices from conference (nov 2011). The number is > 350 mln and this is only for NVIDIA.

Comment: Another numbers from Nvidia: [HPC Directions at NVIDIA](http://www.hpcuserforum.com/presentations/tuscon2013/NVIDIA.pdf#page=12) (49th HPC User Forum, 2013, Tuscon presentation). Cyril Zeller says on slide 12, about 100 millions of CUDA-enabled devices in 2008 and 430 millions in 2013.